# Laravel sign in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I can sign up and details are then added to the database but I can't use info from the database to successfully login. It just brings back the same page with no error messages. This is the UserController code

````php
namespace App\Http\Controllers; 
use App\User; 
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use App\Http\Requests; 
use Auth; 

class UserController extends Controller 

public function getSignin()
{
    return view('user.signin');
}

public function postSignin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'email|required',
        'password' => 'required|min:4'
    ]);
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password')])) {
        return redirect()->route('user.profile');
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```auth file


     protected function validator(array $data)
        {
            return Validator::make($data, [
                'name' => 'required|max:255',
                'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
                'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
            ]);
        }
        /**
         * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
         *
         * @param  array  $data
         * @return User
         */
        protected function create(array $data)
        {
            return User::create([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            ]);
        }
    }
````

Comment: You should remove the validation for a while and then recheck if so the problem is with validation also check what you are getting as your validation errors

Comment: Are you hashing the passwords in the signup code? BTW you should use the inbuild Authorization system that ships with laravel instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: yes the password is hashed in the database.  .when I sign up it logs me in at the same time and enters the data into the database. I think the signin form is causing an error because the email already exists in the database I would like to use the inbuilt authorisation but I think I deleted the login page in error while following the tutorials. I am using a hosted system not artisan so not easy to get the code back.

Comment: IMHO with the details given is difficult to give a meaningful answer, it could be anything. You have to debug your application and see what happens, this package can be of help: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: Are you executing the php artisan make:auth command?

Comment: I am working on a hosted site so I only have access to folders not artisan.  I have added code from the auth.php file above.

Comment: i think register code is already there in your controller while you created project in Auth\RegisterController

Comment: sorry Sandy I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Maybe I need to add the hash check in the code somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started the project again using Laravel's built in login and register system.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you're saving your password with `bcrypt`, but on `Auth::attempt` you pass it in a plain text. Try this:

```
Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password'))])
```